# What is the easiest way to zgrep certain pattern?

Tags: text-processing

I need to zgrep certain period of time, for example: `from 1/Oct/2014 to 31/Mar/2015.`

I was trying to do it like this:

```
find . -name \*.* | xargs zgrep -E '/Oct/2014 | /Nov/2014 | /Dec/2014 | /Jan/2015 | /Feb/2015 | /Mar/2015 | /Feb/2015'| /Mar/2015'
```

but it didnt work. I would wait for a long period of time and I would end up with nothing.

I guess its not important, but my stucture looks like:

```
~/Desktop/logs
├── first_folder
|   ├── 11.11 (folder)
│   |   ├── access_log
│   |   ├── access_log.1.gz
│   |   :
│   |   └── access_log.40.gz
|   └── 11.12 (folder)
│       ├── access_log
│       ├── access_log.1.gz
│       :
│       └── access_log.16.gz
├── second_folder (folder)
|   ├── 31.11 (folder)
│   |   ├── access_log
│   |   ├── access_log.1.gz
│   |   :
│   |   └── access_log.20.gz
|   └── 31.15 (folder)
│       ├── access_log
│       ├── access_log.1.gz
│       :
:       └── access_log.38.gz
└── last_folder
    ├── 91.11 (folder)
    |   ├── access_log
    |   ├── access_log.1.gz
    |   :
    |   └── access_log.25.gz
    └── 91.15 (folder)
        ├── access_log
        ├── access_log.1.gz
        :
        └── access_log.30.gz
```

Comment: In regex, every character is important - so for example `/Oct/2014 | /Nov/2014 ` will only match `/Oct/2014 ` with a trailing space or ` /Nov/2014 ` with leading and trailing spaces - is that really what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably *grouping* is your friend here

```
zgrep -E '/(Oct|Nov|Dec)/2014|/(Jan|Feb|Mar)/2015'
```

so something like

```
find . -type f -name 'access_log*' -exec zgrep -E '/(Oct|Nov|Dec)/2014|/(Jan|Feb|Mar)/2015' {} +
```

Comment: This is neat, it seems to work. What does {}+ stands for? I m newbie

Comment: @vayacondios2015 the `-exec <command> {} +` is GNU `find`'s internal equivalent of `xargs` - it runs `<command>` on each file found, grouping them efficiently  bearing in mind the `ARG_MAX` limit